# Installation problem1

Tags: software-installation, software-center

Error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Hi everyone
I get the above error whenever I try to install something. I am still new on Linux so I don't really know whats going on.
I was actually trying to install `git`.

Comment: Use `sudo`, e.g. `sudo apt-get install git`.

Answer (score 0):

Open Software Center and go to edit > software sources

[image]

Under the `Ubuntu Software` tab, select the `Download from` option to `Main Server`:

[image]

Under the `Other Software` tab, enable the following sources:

- Canonical Partners
- Canonical Partners (Source Code)
- Independent
- Independent (Source Code)

Run `sudo apt-get update` again and try re-installing your package.

[Source](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-fix-this-error-e-unable-to-fetch.html)

Comment: I am using the same command but then I get errors like: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? When I run the update command I get this error: W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @SthembileMthethwa check out new edit

Comment: I still have the same error.